# Mysqli query is only returning one row (last one)

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get all the comment votes from my database table which belongs to the comments in the `$comments` variable (referred to as item_id in the comment_votes table) and is > 0. But, I only get one of the vote row's (the last one) when running the script below. Based on the database table values below I would think i should have 4. Do IN() only return one row or am I doing something else wrong?

```
$comments = "1,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13";

$db_conn = new Database;
$stmt = $db_conn->connect->prepare("SELECT ID FROM `COMMENT_VOTES` WHERE VOTE > 0 AND `ITEM_ID` IN (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $comments);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$votes = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

    array_push($votes, $row['ID']);

}

$votes = implode(",",$votes);
echo $votes;

+---------------------+
|    COMMENT_VOTES    |
+----+---------+------+
| ID | ITEM_ID | VOTE |
+----+---------+------+
| 1  | 12      | 1    |
| 2  | 8       | 0    |
| 3  | 3       | 1    |
| 4  | 22      | 1    |
| 5  | 5       | 0    |
| 6  | 5       | 1    |
| 7  | 5       | 1    |
| 8  | 5       | 0    |
+----+---------+------+
```

Comment: I would expect 3 unique ids `3,5,12` with 4 records so what is `get_result()` and what does it do with the recordset?

Comment: get_result(); gives me field count 1 and num_rows 1

Comment: I would usually expect to see `$stmt->store_result()` before trying to get the row count after executing a prepared statement and `bind_result( $id )` after

Comment: If i do IN(1,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13) it works just fine. So it is some kind of problem with $comments getting run as "1,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial method of approaching this was very similar to your method and like your it failed. A little research suggested that this method would not work as we both found as each item in the `$comments` string really needed it's own placeholder and associated type string which lead me to this:

```
/* output */
$votes=array();

/* original string of IDS */
$comments='1,3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13';

/* create an array from IDS */
$array=explode(',',$comments);

/* create placeholders for each ID */
$placeholders=implode( ',', array_fill( 0, count( $array ), '?' ) );

/* create a type string for each - all going to be `i` */
$types=implode( '', array_fill( 0, count( $array ), 'i' ) );

/* create the sql statement */
$sql=sprintf( 'select `id` from `comment_votes` where `vote` > 0 and `item_id` in ( %s );', $placeholders );

/* create the prepared statement */
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

/* Add the type strings to the beginning of the array */
array_unshift( $array, $types );

if( $stmt ){

    /* bind types and placeholders - 2nd arg passed by reference */
    call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_param'), &$array );

    /* execute the query */
    $result=$stmt->execute();

    /* success */
    if( $result ){

        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $id );
        $rows=$stmt->num_rows;

        printf( 'rows found: %d<br />',$rows );

        /* add found IDs to output */
        while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $votes[]=$id;
        }
        /* tidy up */
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();


        /* do something with output */
        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $votes, true ) );

    } else{
        exit('Error: No results');
    }

} else exit('Error: Prepared statement failed');
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i can't get bind to work. But, i got it working without bind by using `$stmt = $db_conn->connect->prepare("SELECT`ITEM_ID`FROM`COMMENT_VOTES`WHERE VOTE > 0 AND`ITEM_ID`IN ($comment_ids)");`